# Initialize a 2-D array of incrementing integers

Tags: php, arrays, 2d

I need to create a 2D Array of incrementing integers, while the incrementation changes direction diagonally.
I have done so, for N=4 (rows and columns number), but am not able to create a solution for any N: http://pastebin.com/XXue4KT8

Example of the output:

[image: exmaple]

Could anyone give me pointers and hints? I am not asking for a direct solution.

Comment: Unsure exactly what you want as the end result here, can you show a small example with an explanation of what you mean?

Comment: Ok, here is an example for N=4:
http://i.imgur.com/dlVgpcN.png

Answer (score 0):

Start by initializing your matrix using `array_fill()`:

```
$matrix = array_fill(0, $n, array_fill(0, $n, 0));
```

Then pass it through `array_map()`, setting is values as needed. Here's an example that should generate `((1,2),(3,4))` with `n = 2`:

```
$i = 0;
$matrix = array_map(function($row) use ($i) {
   return array_map(function($val) use ($i) {
       return ++$i;
   }, $row);
}, $matrix);
```

(Alternatively, iterate through `$matrix[$i][$j]` in nested for loops.)